# software recommendation to enable viewing of Windows format picture images in Ubuntu

Tags: windows, software-recommendation

I have a CD with medical images from a recent testing procedure, but it says Windows XP or newer is required. I do not have any Windows PC available - we have Mac and Ubuntu. Is there some software I can install to make the CD images viewable?

Comment: Do you have any information about the actual image format? or the manufacturer of the imaging system they were produced on? Do the files have a particular filename extension?

Comment: "Windows" is not an image format. What format are the images actually in? What (make and model of device) have they come from? What's their extension?

Comment: A useful utility is the `file` utility. It will tell you the format of your image files if the are in a reasonably common format. Try something like `file /media/user/CD/imagefilename`.

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is 8 years old, but this answer might be useful for others with the same issue.

Medical images are almost always in the DICOM format (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM)

If you’re given a cd or dvd from a healthcare provider, they will almost certainly assume you don’t have a DICOM viewer on your computer - so the cd will usually contain a viewer (a .exe file) to allow you to access the images. That is the bit that will be Windows specific.

It is very likely that the cd contains the viewer software and a bunch of DICOM files. You can therefore access the files using a DICOM viewer if you install a separate DICOM viewer that works on Ubuntu first.

There are various FOSS (or otherwise free to use) DICOM viewers available for Ubuntu; I’ve used Aeskulap (available in the software centre) in Ubuntu 20.04LTS and 22.04LTS and it works well, but there are others that are free and intuitive to use. Just search online for DICOM viewers and you’ll see some options.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the CD in the Ubuntu computer and open it with Nautilus or your desktop filesystem. If the photo format is not available to Ubuntu, you may need the "restricted-extras" package.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras ubuntu-restricted-addons
```

Even though products *advertise* that you *need* Windows blah blah blah or newer doesn't *actually* mean it won't work on Ubuntu. Very few companies are willing to do product testing on Linux compatibility so for legal (and corporate endorsement) reasons, they only say Windows.

Unless it's some sort of a Windows application or program and not just files, you should be more than capable of viewing the photos.

Even if it is a Windows application, you can probably use the "wine" application to run the .exe or even a Linux version or clone of the equivalent Windows program.